# Compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{9999}\frac1{2\sqrt k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm in trouble when trying to calculate the following sum:

$$\frac1{2\sqrt 1+1}+\frac1{2\sqrt 2+1}+\frac1{2\sqrt 3+1}+\ldots+\frac1{2\sqrt {9999}+1}$$

Since there isn't any formula to calculate the series$\sum\frac1{n^{1/2}}$ and there are square root numbers in the sum, how do you solve this?

Please note that this problem was given in a tournament in which I participated, so it MUST be solvable.

Comment: You could try [Euler-Maclaurin summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Comment: `calculate the following sum` What was the exact wording of the question? It is not clear whether "*calculate*" means closed form (unlikely), or a numerical approximation, or the integer part etc.

Comment: @dxiv Most probably a "simpler" numerical exact value, may be by telescoping the original sum (I've tried some minutes but without success). Btw, I agree it is just vaguely related to the other thread.

Comment: [Turns out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+1%2F(2sqrt(x)%2B1)+from+x%3D1+to+9999) to be around $97.0708$.

Comment: Note that one can try rationalising the denominator to get $$2\sum_{k=1}^{9999}\frac{\sqrt k}{4k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{9999}\frac1{4k-1}$$

Comment: wolfram alpha does not find a closed form, so you probably must be content with a numerical result.

Comment: The result is sufficiently ugly also with just three terms.. can you state what is the complete statement?

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}+1}\approx \sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}-\frac{1}{4k-1}$ for large values of $k$, such sum belongs to the interval $(97,98)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio your type of questions, right

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So, probably the task was to determine the integral part of this series.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Apparently. Jack often finds astonishing simple solutions to very difficult seeming questions. Fascinating!

Comment: Voted to close as this seems another incorrectly transcribed question from some source we cannot view.

Comment: There is no way there is a simple way to write this whole sum. For any prime $5000<p<10000$ there will be a term involving $\sqrt{p}$, and those terms will be linearly independent from each other and from remaining terms in the sum, so there will not be any cancellation involving them.

Comment: So ... perhaps the "tournament" question was in a multiple choice format?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio ... probably the right way to do it.  The numerical value is $97.0707870752\dots$

Comment: @GEdgar: actually a variation of David Quinn's approach is more efficient than mine. The integral of $\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}+1}$ over $(1/2,9999+1/2)$ is $97.0794\ldots$  and by standard (convexity) inequalities the approximation error does not exceed $5\cdot 10^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can get quite a good approximation by evaluating $$\int_1^{9999}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}+1}dx=\sqrt{9999}-1-\frac 12\ln\left(\frac{2\sqrt{9999}+1}{3}\right)\simeq96.89267844$$

Comment: "Quite good" In which (precise) sense?

Comment: Better to replace the LHS with $\int_{1/2}^{9999+1/2}\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}+1}$ and estimate the remainder through the Hermite-Hadamard inequality or similar techniques. To prove $S\leq 98$ is not difficult, to prove $S\geq 97$ is a bit more tricky.